# Usage of "mobile" and "phone" - which one is more common in the UK?

Tags: word-usage, british-english

Similar questions have been asked in the past, but I am curious as to whether this usage has changed as of recent years. Is it more common to describe one's mobile phone as a "mobile" or as a "phone" in the UK? Likewise, is their usage limited to particular groups of people?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to frame a query for [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mobile%20in%20my%20pocket%2Cphone%20in%20my%20pocket&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) that would rule out other uses of the words "mobile" and "phone".  I searched "British English" starting in 1980.  My phrases were "phone in my pocket" and "mobile in my pocket".  Then "phone" was the winner by a wide margin.  From Rosie's suggestion, I also did "mobile phone in my pocket", but that was still smaller.

[image]

Comment: What phrases did you use in your NGram? Please add them to your answer in *plain text*. I'm worried that a search for "phone X" will also count "mobile phone X", and one for "X mobile" will also count "X mobile phone".

Comment: I'd try cell phone versus mobile phone.

Comment: @Lambie We do not use the words "cell phone" to describe a mobile phone in the UK.

Comment: @ChrisDown is right, so searching British English for cell phone (or cellphone) should return no hits.  It probably will, because the tagging of British vs American English is far from perfect (of course you'll also have American usage quoted in genuinely British sources)

Comment: @ChrisDown You know what? I just do not understand how people read. I wrote cell phone **versus** mobile phone. Does that not suggest to you that I know that in the UK you say mobile or mobile phone? And in the US, we say cell phone?

Comment: @Lambie This entire question is about UK usage: not only is it the case that the question specifically requests information about BrE, but it's also literally tagged [british-english]. How would including a compound that we simply do not have in British English have any useful effect on the answer?

Comment: @ChrisDown I just thought a contrast might bring up something useful. Ngrams cannot track actual speech. Anyway, sorry this caused do much trouble.

Comment: A comparison between "Call him on his mobile" and "call him on his phone" would be **completely** different, I think.

Comment: @AndrewLeach ... good idea.  "Call his mobile" vs. "call his phone" are reversed: in American English, "phone" wins and in British English "mobile" wins.